# How does certain classes cause automatic instantiation and others do not?

Tags: c#, instantiation

In the below code there is only one instance of the StringBuilder and test2 and test3 are actually pointing to the original instance of `new StringBuilder()`

```
StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder("test");
StringBuilder test2;
StringBuilder test3;
test2 = test;
test3 = test2;
```

So I can append test3 and it will append the original test.

I understand that String is immutable but take the code below

```
String test = new String("test");
String test2;
String test3;
test2=test;
test3=test2;
```

Using the same logical inference it should behave exactly the same way yet if I change test3 it has nothing to do with test which means when I do `test=test2` it is actually doing something like `test2=new test` and `test3 = new test2` this seems highly illogical to me. Suppose I wanted to make my own simple byte class one that behaves like StringBuilder and one that behaves like String what exactly in the StringBuilder class allows the instance to be passed and what in the String class allows it to automatically create a new instance just by using the equal sign? I don't understand how test=test2 is logically consistent between the 2 examples I gave. It actually looks unpredictably illogical to me. What line of code actually makes this difference between the 2 classes?

When you use an equal sign with an instance of StringBuilder it passes the instance but when you use an equal sign with an instance of String it magically creates a new instance. What line of code in the class determines how the equal sign behaves like this? I don't like this because it actually changes the meaning of the equal sign so I would like to know at least what piece of code changes the definition of the equal sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What line of code actually makes this difference between the 2 classes

The line of code you've not shown. To append to `test3` as a `string`, you perform an additional assignment:

```
test3 = test3 + "abc";
```

(If you don't perform an assignment here, the newly generated `string` is immediately eligible for garbage collection since nothing is holding a reference to it)

To append to `test3` as a `StringBuilder`, there's no additional assignment:

```
test3.Append("abc");
```

---

> Suppose I wanted to make my own simple byte class one that behaves like StringBuilder and one that behaves like String

To create a class like `StringBuilder`, you would create a class that modifies its internal state when "modifying" methods like `Append()` are called on it. To create a class like `String`, you would create a class that *creates* new instances of the class containing the updated state created by the "modifying" methods. Such methods would *not* update their own internal state.

This is all about *implementing* immutable classes - there's no compiler magic, it's just a design decision.

Comment: Thank you. I think I confused the 2 because I thought deleting test would delete test3 but the Garbage Collector handles that and that is what threw me off I think.